# SQL Case issue using where

Tags: sql

I'm a previous SAS dominated user now in SQL. My case statement isn't working like SAS, where it would only include those with a jb_tyvm=1.

```
SELECT 
    [AccountId],
    CASE
        WHEN TyvmPromoCode IS NULL 
            THEN 0
            ELSE 1
    END AS jb_TYVM,
    TotalCollected
FROM 
    [Football_Kick_Off].[dbo].[Cove_BaseData]
WHERE 
    jb_tyvm = 1
ORDER BY
    jb_tyvm DESC
```

Comment: In SQL, the WHERE clause is evaluated _before_ the SELECT clause. I.e. the column alias hasn't yet been defined.

Comment: Easy fix, `WHERE TyvmPromoCode IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: Correct, you should only need to change the query to ... WHERE TyvmPromoCode IS NOT NULL

Comment: BTW, it's a `case` _expression_.

Comment: Are you asking if you can use a CASE expression in a WHERE clause?  Why don't you try it and see?  Something like `where 1= case when (condition) then 1 else 0 end`

Comment: Did you mean to use the same name for the columns, but with different capitalization? That gets confusing. It's not clear to me if you're trying to use the case-result in the where clause or if your table has an actual column named jb_tyvm.